# Laravel storage put() or putFileAs() to an S3 directory fails for 1gb or larger files

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

Good day!

I am having issues with storing files to our S3 when the file is large (1gb+).
Only a supervisord entry like this is show:

```
[2019-10-02 03:29:09][18] Processing: App\Jobs\JobMoveToS3
[2019-10-02 03:30:39][18] Processing: App\Jobs\JobMoveToS3
[2019-10-02 03:32:10][18] Processing: App\Jobs\JobMoveToS3
[2019-10-02 03:33:10][18] Failed:     App\Jobs\JobMoveToS3
```

Could this have something to do with memory limit?  We are using the DigitalOcean 5dollar package.

Answer (score 1):

try to update your php.ini:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 2048M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 2048M
```